# What is the dual of $C(K,E)$, where $K$ is a compact space and $E$ a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, tensor-products, dual-spaces

Let $K$ be a compact, Hausdorff topological space and $E$, a Banach space.

**Question**. Is there a nice description of  the dual of $C(K,E)$, the space of continuous functions from $K$ to $E$, with the supremum norm?

This is of course easy if either $K$ is a point, or $E$ is one-dimensional.  So I suspect the general picture should be a combination of these two simpler cases.  Maybe $E'$ valued Borel measures on $K$?

Comment: Probably a form of $E$-valued measures will form the dual, with a suitable integration theory forming the link? I think such things will have been studied before. But [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_measure) does not mention duals..

Comment: Similar question on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/354944/2060).